# Is there a way to advertise new tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have recently created a new tag. I wanted to know if there is way I can improve the visibility of this tag so that others can start using it?

Comment: The tag in question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-debt

Comment: Ask a question on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93387/is-there-a-way-to-advertise-new-tag), and remember to include a link to the tag you created!

Answer (score 2):

All tags are automatically included in the auto-complete drop-downs. If you'd type `design-d` you will see your tag as one of 4 to choose from.

Of course, they are sorted by popularity, so it's an egg-chicken problem - how to make tag popular when initially it's very hard to find. But I see no good solution for that.

---

In particular case of the tag you've created, I kind of feel it's redundant. You've used tags [design](/questions/tagged/design) [design-debt](/questions/tagged/design-debt), so it might as well have been tagged [design](/questions/tagged/design) [technical-debt](/questions/tagged/technical-debt)